# Remove IndexError from if statement - Maze solving Software

Tags: python, list, maze

So I was looking to code a maze-solving program and I already failed with the importing of the maze. This is my Code:

```
def import_maze(filename):
    temp = open(filename, 'r')
    x, y = temp.readline().split(" ")
    maze = [[0 for x in range(int(y))] for x in range(int(x))]
    local_counter, counter, startx, starty = 0, 0, 0, 0
    temp.readline()
    with open(filename) as file:
        maze = [[letter for letter in list(line)] for line in file]

    for i in range(1, int(y)):
        for z in range(0, int(x)):
            if maze[i][z] == '#':
                local_counter += 1
            if local_counter < 2 and maze[i][z] == " ":
                counter += 1
            if maze[i][z] == 'K':
                startx, starty = i, z
        local_counter = 0

    return maze, startx, starty, counter


maze, startx, starty, counter = import_maze("kassiopeia0.txt")

print(counter, "\n", startx, ":", starty, "\n", maze)
```

To explain a bit: The local_counter is "showing" the borders of the maze. So i can count the blank elements in the array. The quantity of them will be saved in counter, wich I need for me recusion basis.
And the Error Message I revieve is:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/Anton/PycharmProjects/BWINF_Aufgabe_1/Wegfinden.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Anton/PycharmProjects/BWINF_Aufgabe_1/Wegfinden.py", line 27, in <module>
    maze, startx, starty, counter = import_maze("kassiopeia0.txt")
  File "C:/Users/Anton/PycharmProjects/BWINF_Aufgabe_1/Wegfinden.py", line 16, in import_maze
    if maze[i][z] == '#':
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Lastly here is the kassiopeia0.txt-file:

```
6 9
#########
#  #    #
#  # #  #
#  K #  #
#    #  #
#########
```

Sry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying a 6-by-9 maze in the header line of kassiopeia0.txt, but the rest of the file contains a 9-by-6 maze.

Swap the 6 and 9 and the maze should read fine.  It did for me.

Answer (score 1):

@Luke is right. I'd suggest you the following code:

```
def import_maze(filename):

    with open(filename) as f:
        maze = [[letter for letter in line.strip()] for line in f.readlines() if line.strip()]

    local_counter, counter, startx, starty = 0, 0, 0, 0

    for y, row in enumerate(maze):
        for x, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell == '#':
                local_counter += 1

            elif local_counter < 2 and cell == ' ':
                counter += 1

            elif cell == 'K':
                startx, starty = x, y

        local_counter = 0

    return maze, startx, starty, counter
```

and your file is:

```
#########
#  #    #
#  # #  #
#  K #  #
#    #  #
#########
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much and also thanks to @Luke! =D